# Linux sometimes hangs when it attempts to go into sleep/suspend

Tags: suspend, freeze, sleep

Sometimes my PC (Linux Mint 18.1) hangs when it tries to go into sleep/suspend by itself after inactivity. When I come back to it, the monitor is in standby but the computer is still running (fans and lights still on). There is no response from mouse and keyboard; I have to do a hard reset to get out of this.

I don't know when or why this problem sneaked into my system. It might be related to a wifi adapter (TP-Link TL-WDN4800 N900) that I have installed a couple of month ago.

I already tried to solve the problems using different Kernels (4.4.0.93, 4.10.0.33, 4.11.0.14), without luck.

There is a ATI graphics adapter, but I haven't changed anything related to it and it was working before the problem sneaked in.

This is the last part of `/var/log/syslog` before the machine freezes:

```
15:53:12 NetworkManager[1275]: <info>  [1504014792.3767] manager: sleep requested (sleeping: no  enabled: yes)
15:53:12 NetworkManager[1275]: <info>  [1504014792.3768] manager: sleeping...
15:53:12 NetworkManager[1275]: <info>  [1504014792.3769] manager: NetworkManager state is now ASLEEP
15:53:12 NetworkManager[1275]: <info>  [1504014792.3773] device (wls1): state change: activated -> deactivating (reason 'sleeping') [100 110 37]
15:53:12 NetworkManager[1275]: <info>  [1504014792.3867] device (wls1): state change: deactivating -> disconnected (reason 'sleeping') [110 30 37]
15:53:12 avahi-daemon[1209]: Withdrawing address record for [ADDR REMOVED] on wls1.
15:53:12 avahi-daemon[1209]: Leaving mDNS multicast group on interface wls1.IPv6 with address [ADDR REMOVED].
15:53:12 avahi-daemon[1209]: Interface wls1.IPv6 no longer relevant for mDNS.
15:53:12 NetworkManager[1275]: <info>  [1504014792.4195] dhcp4 (wls1): canceled DHCP transaction, DHCP client pid 16722
15:53:12 NetworkManager[1275]: <info>  [1504014792.4196] dhcp4 (wls1): state changed bound -> done
15:53:12 kernel: [29251.790575] wls1: deauthenticating from [ADDR REMOVED] by local choice (Reason: 3=DEAUTH_LEAVING)
15:53:12 wpa_supplicant[1472]: wls1: CTRL-EVENT-DISCONNECTED bssid=[ADDR REMOVED] reason=3 locally_generated=1
15:53:12 NetworkManager[1275]: <info>  [1504014792.4250] dns-mgr: Removing DNS information from /sbin/resolvconf
15:53:12 avahi-daemon[1209]: Withdrawing address record for 192.168.178.14 on wls1.
15:53:12 avahi-daemon[1209]: Leaving mDNS multicast group on interface wls1.IPv4 with address 192.168.178.14.
15:53:12 avahi-daemon[1209]: Interface wls1.IPv4 no longer relevant for mDNS.
15:53:12 wpa_supplicant[1472]: wls1: CTRL-EVENT-REGDOM-CHANGE init=CORE type=WORLD
15:53:12 kernel: [29251.799071] cfg80211: World regulatory domain updated:
15:53:12 kernel: [29251.799075] cfg80211:  DFS Master region: unset
15:53:12 kernel: [29251.799077] cfg80211:   (start_freq - end_freq @ bandwidth), (max_antenna_gain, max_eirp), (dfs_cac_time)
15:53:12 kernel: [29251.799081] cfg80211:   (2402000 KHz - 2472000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (N/A)
15:53:12 kernel: [29251.799084] cfg80211:   (2457000 KHz - 2482000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (N/A)
15:53:12 kernel: [29251.799086] cfg80211:   (2474000 KHz - 2494000 KHz @ 20000 KHz), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (N/A)
15:53:12 kernel: [29251.799089] cfg80211:   (5170000 KHz - 5250000 KHz @ 80000 KHz, 160000 KHz AUTO), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (N/A)
15:53:12 kernel: [29251.799092] cfg80211:   (5250000 KHz - 5330000 KHz @ 80000 KHz, 160000 KHz AUTO), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (0 s)
15:53:12 kernel: [29251.799095] cfg80211:   (5490000 KHz - 5730000 KHz @ 160000 KHz), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (0 s)
15:53:12 kernel: [29251.799097] cfg80211:   (5735000 KHz - 5835000 KHz @ 80000 KHz), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (N/A)
15:53:12 kernel: [29251.799099] cfg80211:   (57240000 KHz - 63720000 KHz @ 2160000 KHz), (N/A, 0 mBm), (N/A)
15:53:12 dbus[1251]: [system] Activating via systemd: service name='org.freedesktop.nm_dispatcher' unit='dbus-org.freedesktop.nm-dispatcher.service'
15:53:12 NetworkManager[1275]: <warn>  [1504014792.4609] sup-iface[[ADDR REMOVED],wls1]: connection disconnected (reason -3)
15:53:12 NetworkManager[1275]: <info>  [1504014792.4610] device (wls1): supplicant interface state: completed -> disconnected
15:53:12 NetworkManager[1275]: <info>  [1504014792.4617] device (wls1): state change: disconnected -> unmanaged (reason 'sleeping') [30 10 37]
15:53:12 systemd[1]: Starting Network Manager Script Dispatcher Service...
15:53:12 systemd[1]: Reached target Sleep.
15:53:12 systemd[1]: Starting Suspend...
15:53:12 dbus[1251]: [system] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.nm_dispatcher'
15:53:12 systemd[1]: Started Network Manager Script Dispatcher Service.
15:53:12 nm-dispatcher: req:1 'down' [wls1]: new request (2 scripts)
15:53:12 nm-dispatcher: req:1 'down' [wls1]: start running ordered scripts...
15:53:12 wpa_supplicant[1472]: nl80211: deinit ifname=wls1 disabled_11b_rates=0
15:53:13 ntpd[1683]: Deleting interface #11 wls1, 192.168.178.14#123, interface stats: received=136, sent=136, dropped=0, active_time=3772 secs
15:53:13 ntpd[1683]: [ADDR REMOVED] local addr 192.168.178.14 -> <null>
15:53:13 ntpd[1683]: [ADDR REMOVED] local addr 192.168.178.14 -> <null>
15:53:13 ntpd[1683]: [ADDR REMOVED] local addr 192.168.178.14 -> <null>
15:53:13 ntpd[1683]: [ADDR REMOVED] local addr 192.168.178.14 -> <null>
15:53:13 ntpd[1683]: [ADDR REMOVED] local addr 192.168.178.14 -> <null>
15:53:13 ntpd[1683]: [ADDR REMOVED] local addr 192.168.178.14 -> <null>
15:53:13 ntpd[1683]: [ADDR REMOVED] local addr 192.168.178.14 -> <null>
15:53:13 ntpd[1683]: [ADDR REMOVED] local addr 192.168.178.14 -> <null>
15:53:13 ntpd[1683]: [ADDR REMOVED] local addr 192.168.178.14 -> <null>
15:53:13 ntpd[1683]: [ADDR REMOVED] local addr 192.168.178.14 -> <null>
15:53:13 ntpd[1683]: [ADDR REMOVED] local addr 192.168.178.14 -> <null>
15:53:13 ntpd[1683]: [ADDR REMOVED] local addr 192.168.178.14 -> <null>
15:53:13 ntpd[1683]: [ADDR REMOVED] local addr 192.168.178.14 -> <null>
15:53:13 ntpd[1683]: Deleting interface #12 wls1, [ADDR REMOVED]#123, interface stats: received=0, sent=0, dropped=0, active_time=3772 secs
15:53:22 systemd-sleep[17957]: Selected interface 'wls1'
15:53:22 systemd-sleep[17957]: 'SUSPEND' command timed out.
15:53:22 systemd-sleep[17959]: /lib/systemd/system-sleep/wpasupplicant failed with error code 254.
15:53:22 systemd-sleep[17957]: Suspending system...
```

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: Disable the wifi adapter and see if the problem persists.

Answer (score 0):

Some apps have an option to disable hibernate while active. For example, transmission-gtk has the option `Inhibit hibernation when torrents are active`. Try to uncheck it (in my case it fixed the issue).

P.S. Arch linux, AMD Phenom2, etc.